# How to Compare Only Date of dateTime objects in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I get Exception when i try to compare only date How  i resolve it?

```
using (var db = dataBase())
{
    return db.usedata.Where(x => x.ProductFK == id && x.DateTime.Date  >= startDate.Date && x.DateTime.Date <= endDate.Date)
       .Select(x => x).ToList();
}
```

Comment: use `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` method

Comment: you replace the `x.DateTime.Date` with `DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateTime)`

Comment: When someone has suggested a fix, you should spend time *trying* to understand how to use it before asking for more help. Given that you asked "how" (with far more question marks than are necessary...) only 23 seconds after the comment from Hopeless, that suggests you didn't do any research.

Comment: Additionally, you should *always* specify any errors that you're getting when you ask a question.